# Function or loop to repeat task (2)

Tags: r, function, loops, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to create a loop or a function for the dataset below.

For overall_health, outlook_life, and health_mental- I am trying to calculate the proportion by sex, age_group, income and education. In addition, I would like to create two separate outputs by the geography (area1 and area2).

Please note that I do not want to use the pivot longer function.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Here's the a sample data frame (survey data):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame (overall_health = c("poor", "good", "excellent", "poor", "good", "poor", "poor", "excellent"),
                  outlook_life = c("good", "excellent", "excellent", "poor", "excellent", "poor", "excellent", "poor"),
                  health_mental = c("poor", "poor", "excellent", "poor", "poor", "poor", "excellent", "good"),
                  sex = c("F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M"),
                  age_group = c("50-54", "60-64", "80+", "70-74", "40-44", "45-49", "60-64", "65-69"),
                  income = c("$<40,000", "$50,000-79,000", "$80,000-110,000", "$111,000+", "$<40,000", "$<40,000", "$50,000-79,000", "$80,000-110,000"),
                  education = c("HS", "College", "Bachelors", "Masters", "HS", "College", "Bachelors", "Masters"),
                  geography= c("area1", "area2", "area1", "area2", "area2", "area1", "area2", "area1"))
```

Typically, one would calculate the proportion by age group as such:

```
df_new <- df %>%
  group_by(overall_health, age_group, geography) %>%
  summarise(count = n(),
            total = 8,
            proportion = count/total *100)
```

However, I would like to create a loop/function to calculate these portions for overall_health, outlook_life, and health_mental by: age_group, sex, income, education (in geography= "area1")
I would like to do the same or geography= "area 2".

So for overall_health, outlook_life, and health_mental I would have multiple outputs by age_group, sex, income, education that look like this:

overall_health x age_group
[image]

outlook_life x age_group
[image]

health_mental x age_group
[image]

overall_health x sex
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)


## unique geographies:
geos <- unique(df$geography)

## You can input combinations to a list to iterate over and label accordingly.
vars <- c("health_mental", "overall_health", "outlook_life")

## expand.grid will create every possible combination between the two vectors you supply it:
combinations <- expand.grid(c("age_group", "sex"), vars, stringsAsFactors = F)

combinations$label <- paste(combinations$Var1, combinations$Var2, sep = "_")

## list to output dataframe results to:
output <- list()

## Outer for loop will iterate through each of your geographies.
for (geo in geos){
  ## Inner loop will iterate through each of your combinations
  for (combo in 1:nrow(combinations)){
    ## outputs are labelled based on combination + geo and stored in output list.
    output_label <- paste(combinations[[combo,"label"]],geo,sep="_")
    temp <- df %>%
                filter(geography == geo) %>%
                group_by_at(combinations[combo,1:2] %>% unlist()%>%unname()) %>%
                summarise(count = n(),
                          total = nrow(.),
                          proportion = count/nrow(.) *100)
    output[[output_label]] <- temp
    
    # You could also export each csv iteratively, with proper labelling automatically as well:
    #write.csv(temp, paste0("insert_file_path", output_label, ".csv"))
  }
}
```

Dataframes can be accessed through the lists by their list label:

```
## all dataframes:
output

## Overall Health x Age Group for Area 1:
output$overall_health_x_age_group_area1
## or
output[["overall_health_x_age_group_area1"]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful. One dilemma I still have though is that I have a lot of variables, aside from overall_health, health_mental, outlook_life. Is there a way to streamline the script to loop through many columns?

Comment: Just modified! you'll just have to input the unique variables you'd like to compare against "age" and "sex" into the vars vector. You could make this easier if you just subset colnames on your data frame and pass that to vars as well.